# Generate Hash Value for Nested JSON Object

Tags: python, json, go, hash, md5

I have two nested JSON objects with different order of elements and would like to generate hash value for both. Now, I'm comparing these two hash  values and it needs to be same. How can I achieve this mechanism?

### First JSON Object

```
{
   "X":{
      "Y":[
         {
            "A":"1",
            "B":{
               "b1":"2",
               "b2":"2"
            }
         },
         {
            "C":"4",
            "D":{
               "d1":"5",
               "d2":"6"
            }
         },
      ],
      "Z":[
         {
            "E":{
               "e1":"7",
               "e2":"8"
            },
            "F":"9"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

### Second JSON Object

```
{
   "X":{
      "Y":[
         {
            "C":"4",
            "D":{
               "d1":"5",
               "d2":"6"
            }
         },
         {
            "A":"1",
            "B":{
               "b1":"2",
               "b2":"2"
            }
         },
      ],
      "Z":[
         {
            "E":{
               "e1":"7",
               "e2":"8"
            },
            "F":"9"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So, here goal is I want to generate same hash value for both JSON object. How can I achieve this in Python or Golang?

Comment: I assume you're going to generate a hash on the JSON string, and not the unpacked object -- that wouldn't make sense.  So, what have you tried?  Python's hash module is well-documented.

Comment: A JSON document is a sequence of bytes. If this sequence of bytes is different you will get a different hash. If two different JSON documents are semantically "the same" (e.g. arrays are considered "unordered") you will have to find a canonical representation and reformat to that canonical representation before hashing. But basically this sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: I have tried Python's hash module. For both above JSON, it return different hash values as expected. But, here I'm looking for same hash value generated without considering order of the elements inside JSON, which is not possible as string/byte sequence changes it will automatcally changes hash value. So, in simple words json.dump(sort_keys=true) with option like sort_values=tru as well so that it will be always sorted and sequence will remain same all time. @TimRoberts

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. @Volker

Answer (score -1):

The JSON object is unsorted as well the map[string]interface{}, so you should sort the maps. However, sorting could be complicated and time consuming.

Instead of using the objects I would like to use the JSON as string, this way the JSON can be Unmarshaled and the string can be sorted to create the SHA value.

```golang
var json1 = `
{
    "X": {
        "Y": [
            {
                "A": "1",
                "B": {
                    "b1": "2",
                    "b2": "2"
                }
            },
            {
                "C": "4",
                "D": {
                    "d1": "5",
                    "d2": "6"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Z": [
            {
                "E": {
                    "e1": "7",
                    "e2": "8"
                },
                "F": "9"
            }
        ]
    }
}
`

var json2 = `
{
    "X": {
        "Y": [
            {
                "C": "4",
                "D": {
                    "d1": "5",
                    "d2": "6"
                }
            },
            {
                "A": "1",
                "B": {
                    "b1": "2",
                    "b2": "2"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Z": [
            {
                "E": {
                    "e1": "7",
                    "e2": "8"
                },
                "F": "9"
            }
        ]
    }
}
`

type JSON struct {
    X struct {
        Y []struct {
            A string `json:"A"`
            B struct {
                B1 string `json:"b1"`
                B2 string `json:"b2"`
            } `json:"B"`
            C string `json:"C"`
            D struct {
                D1 string `json:"d1"`
                D2 string `json:"d2"`
            } `json:"D"`
        } `json:"Y"`
        Z []struct {
            E struct {
                E1 string `json:"e1"`
                E2 string `json:"e2"`
            } `json:"E"`
            F string `json:"F"`
        } `json:"Z"`
    } `json:"X"`
}

func SortString(w string) string {
    s := strings.Split(w, "")
    sort.Strings(s)
    return strings.Join(s, "")
}

func main() {
    var v1, v2 interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(json1), &v1)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(json2), &v2)
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(v1, v2))

    var m1, m2 JSON
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(json1), &m1)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(json2), &m2)
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(m1, m2))

    json1 = SortString(json1)
    json2 = SortString(json2)
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(json1, json2))
}
```

Keep in mind that the objects are unsorted, so you should evaluate if creating a JSONSort function is important (considering that JSON could be different each time).

```golang
go run json.go
false
false
true
```